# WordPress : Add a button that allows a visitor to suggest content in a post

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I would like to add a button to each WordPress post to allow a visitor to complete the content of a post. Side back end, I would like to have access to the various suggestions offered to then integrate them manually.

Any ideas ? 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to make your blog a Wikipedia style? If you want people to write content for you then simply add a comment box and don't give yourself headache with advanced development.